# How to change scss variable based on className?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I am trying to make light/dark mode in react using scss

App.jsx

```
  const { theme } = useToggleTheme();

  return (
    <div className={`app ${theme}`}>
      <Navbar />
    </div>
  );
```

it toggles between app light and app dark, and in scss

variables.scss

```
$app-theme: dark;

$colors: (
  light: (
    background: #ffffff,
    text: #000000,
  ),
  dark: (
    background: #222222,
    text: #ffffff,
  ),
);

@function getColor($name) {
  @return map-get(map-get($colors, #{$app-theme}), $name);
}
```

Instead of writing manually dark/light in $app-theme, i am trying to assign any value that is in ${theme} aka light or dark, and later use it like

app.scss

```
@import "./variables.scss";

background-color: getColor(background);
color: getColor(text);
```

if $app-theme is dark it shows dark colors and vice versa